# nodejs http request immediately after adding a new address result in EADDRNOTAVAIL

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, ipv6

```
//nodejs code

var ip=<some_ip_address>;
//for me it is 2001:250:401:3611:50c6:6b18:e8f7:f882

exec('powershell new-netipaddress '+ip+' -InterfaceAlias WLAN',(e,so,se)=>{
    http.request({
        host:'2404:6800:4005:805::200e',//just use google as an example
        family:6,
        localAddress:ip
    },(res)=>{
        console.log('reachable');
    }).on('error',(e)=>{
        console.log(e);
    })
}).stdin.end();
```

then output

```
{[Error: bind EADDRNOTAVAIL 2001:250:401:3611:50c6:6b18:e8f7:f882]
code: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
errno: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
syscall: 'bind',
address: '2001:250:401:3611:50c6:6b18:e8f7:f882' }
```

the 2nd time 
(actually I am testing address , since our DHCP-stateless is broken)

```
{ [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 2404:6800:4005:805::200e:80]
code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '2404:6800:4005:805::200e',
port: 80 }
```

me can draw from the 2nd time output,

new-netipaddress did add the address properly, so the callback runs well(although timeout, which we designed it to be)

but in 1st time the callback failed with EADDRNOTAVAIL

so why it failed with the first run? and how to avoid it?

Comment: Did the address leave the tentative state when you made the request. It might take a short time for Duplicate Address Detection to complete and the address to become available for use

Comment: @SanderSteffann I think you are right but it happens too fast for me to check.I exec('powershell get-netipaddress') in the callback, the addressState is preferred instead of tentative......But I believe the address is not usable immediately after added, it is just too fast. so, what should I do to avoid it?

Comment: @SanderSteffann dramatically I find the solution. I  invoke the request after execSync('powershell get-netipaddress'), then the addressState is preferred,  and my request can work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @SanderSteffann 's knowledge on tentative address, I think of a solution but may not be very good

```
exec('powershell new-netipaddress '+ip+' -InterfaceAlias WLAN',(e,so,se)=>{
    http.request({
    host:'2404:6800:4005:805::200e',//just use google as an example
    family:6,
    localAddress:ip
},(res)=>{
    console.log('reachable');
}).on('error',(e)=>{
    console.log(e);
})
}).stdin.end();


exec('powershell new-netipaddress '+ip+' -InterfaceAlias WLAN',(e,so,se)=>{
execSync('powershell get-netipaddress '+ip)
    http.request({
    host:'2404:6800:4005:805::200e',//just use google as an example
    family:6,
    localAddress:ip
},(res)=>{
    console.log('reachable');
}).on('error',(e)=>{
    console.log(e);
})
}).stdin.end();
```

**`line 2:++++execSync('powershell get-netipaddress '+ip)`**